# BLE connection iPhone through Settings

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Current status , I have a BLE Device which uses ANCS so I thought this is the place ot ask the question.

My BLE device lights an LED when my phone rings and I also receive the ANCS messages on my iPHone in the Notification center.

I want to build an app that interacts with the BLE device that has the ANCS  and have an options section, I have the ability to to connect to my BLE device by doing a scan and than connecting, But my question is when i am connected to the BLE Device with my iPhone and receive ANCS messages , How do I also connect my App to the BLE device and communicate with it , while it is connected to my iPhone.

Any help guidance direction is greatly appreciated.

JZ

Comment: What have you tried so far?, what are you planning on building this app with?  I would suggest you add alot more information to this post so that people may be able to help you better.

Comment: thank you ! I am building iOS , I have tried referencing iWatch sample code but this has not helped as of yet, Let me try to clarify , I currently have an app that searches for BLE devices I can connect to my BLE device from the app, but when my iPhone is paired to the same BLE device I cannot figure out how to read / write to the BLE device from my App, When I scan for devices the BLE device does not show when it is paired from my iPhone.

Comment: Hey facing the same problem , did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589836/ios-bluetooth-le-unable-to-connect-using-stored-pairing-data) post will solve your issue, but it sounds similar to your problem and might point you in the right direction (iOS isnt really my thing, so I cant give you much information)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great ! I will give it a try.

Comment: Bah, sorry I couldn't be more help. Good luck